# Insert Audio File Into Mysql Database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

How can we insert audio files in to  MYSQL Database using JAVA DATABASE CONNECTIVITY connectivity

For inserting image we use

```
 psmnt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO upload_data(user_id,photo) "
                            + "values(?,?)");

            psmnt.setLong(1, userId);

            fis = new FileInputStream(photoFile);
            psmnt.setBinaryStream(2, (InputStream) fis, (int) (photoFile
                    .length()));
            /*
             * executeUpdate() method execute specified sql query. Here this
             * query insert data and image from specified address.
             */
            int s = psmnt.executeUpdate();
```

To insert an audio file in 3gp format , what will be the code using JDBC

Comment: I would recommend storing the audio file elsewhere (served by Apache) and store the link to that file in MySQL. This way you can stick that file on a CDN too if needed.

Comment: @Harry Joy no i did'nt. I have given the type mediumblob for photo. for auido files wat will we give in mysql db

Comment: @lobster1234 . My requirement is to store the audio file in mysql db

Comment: use the same type as for image (BLOB)

Comment: @manu as said by lobster1234 it always better to store them as flat file and just store the path of the file in db.. Because once you have more records its not efficient to get actual audio data read from table and rendered as output.. You can restrict the file access through apache configuration.. Even if ur client asks u to store only in db , explain him and drive him to do this way

Comment: You do realize that you're going to grind the disk everytime you query this table, since BLOB type results are not cached afaik? TBH this is a recipe for disaster when it comes to scaling and performance of your system.

Comment: @lobster1234 . yes u r right  lobster1234 .. thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should be exactly the same: you will need to make sure your audio file is small enough to fit into the column (mediumblob is 16MBits or there abouts if I recall correctly. The database doesn't care if its audio or image data.

For the sake of discussion:

```
psmnt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO upload_data(user_id,audiofile) "
                            + "values(?,?)");

            psmnt.setLong(1, userId);

            fis = new FileInputStream(audioFile);
            psmnt.setBinaryStream(2, (InputStream) fis, (int) (audioFile
                    .length()));
            /*
             * executeUpdate() method execute specified sql query. Here this
             * query insert data and image from specified address.
             */
            int s = psmnt.executeUpdate();
```

Seems fair?